# Почему не добавляется доп поле в категорию wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Делал по [этой](https://wp-kama.ru/id_740/blok-proizvolnyih-poley-v-adminke-wordpress-svoimi-rukami.html) инструкции, но поле на странице редактирования категории не добавилось

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_extra_fields', 1);
function my_extra_fields() {
    add_meta_box( 'extra_fields', 'Дополнительные поля', 'extra_fields_box_func', 'edit-category', 'normal', 'high'  );
}
function extra_fields_box_func( $post ){ ?>
    <p>123</p>
<?php }
```

Comment: Потому что для категорий добавляется через [category_add_form_fields](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/category_add_form_fields) и без использования `add_meta_box()`.

Comment: @Simon так поле выводится на странице добавления категории, но при редактировании его нет

Comment: Для этого есть еще один хук edit_category_form_fields